# Regex with "r" read from file doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, regex, file-io, configparser

I might have pretty basic question about regex. I have the following regex, which when hardcoded int the application work fine, but then I read it with ConfigParser doesn't seem to work:

```
r"\[[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\]"
```

The way how I read it is :

```
Config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
Config.read("test.conf")
test_regex = Config.get("test","test_regex")
search_pattern = re.compile(test_regex)

test_result = search_pattern.findall(text_to_parse)
```

The part of the test.conf

```
[test]
test_regex=r"\[[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\]"
```

The input for testing might be something as follows:

```
text_to_parse = " Here is the [TEST-DONE]" // Success: my regex is extracting [TEST-DONE]
text_to_parse = " Here is the some text" // Failure my regex returns empty list
```

Any solution for this issue?
Thanks a lot,
Serhiy.

EDIT: was my attention error, as I mention in the comment to answer, but the solution of remotion of the r from regex when it's in the file helped a lot.

Comment: Show the relevant bit of test.conf.

Comment: No, no-one can help you on the basis of this information. Show a complete, correct, and concise code example, and an erroneous session, and explain what is erroneous about it. http://sscce.org/

Comment: `print test_regex` and see what you get. Dont remember not to use `r` or quotes in the config file; from a quick look at the docs you don't quote values in those config files.

Comment: @Marcin I think the information provided except the test.conf file was quite clear. And dont come here with sscce just for trolling around.

Comment: @Marcin: I have to agree. The question isn't as bad as you make it seem, especially the code sample *is* complete, correct and concise, only the config file input was missing.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have tried removing r from text file and putting \\ instaed of \ but didn't work either, just always returns empty list.

Comment: Are you certain the given regex does what you expect? I just tried this (without the config file involved) and the return from your test data is an empty list.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I have tried to print the text_regex and the output is the following: `r"\[[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\]"`

Comment: @Serhiy Sure, it was clear, but in no way was it complete.

Comment: @NiklasB. thats what happens when you try to defend yourself against people who doesn't seem to know how to respond the question but just wine because some line of code is missing. I know its hard to help when something is missing, but anyways I won't accept people coming with sscce and other things when its pretty clear what I wanted and what I had.

Comment: @Serhiy: I think they are very able to answer such a (rather simple) question. It's just that you didn't follow the rules right from the beginning. Somebody noticed and wrote a comment, which is okay. I just don't understand why they don't remove their downvotes once the question is improved.

Comment: @NiklasB. still need to master the asking question technique ;) thanks for help and support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to parse the string according to the Python rules:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(conf.get("test", "test_regex"))
'\\[[+-]?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?\\]'
```

But it's easier to just change your config file to contain the unescaped regex in the first place:

```
[test]
test_regex=\[[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\] 

>>> conf.get("test", "test_regex")
'\\[[+-]?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?\\]'
```

That said, the regex doesn't seem to do what you think it does. It matches:

- opening bracket
- followed by optional + or - sign
- followed by a number of digits
- optionally followed by a dot and more digits
- followed by closing bracket

Example:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\[[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\]', 'foo [+10] bar [-3.5]')
['[+10]', '[-3.5]']
```

Of course there will not be any matches in both of your example strings, because they don't contain the pattern!

Comment: Bingo, my fault in configuration files I switched without noticing the regexes and in application logic that didn't made any sense. Thanks a lot both for explaining the remotion of "r" from regex and indetification of my error :S.

Comment: And by the way importing ast could be a solution but not in my case.. because the machine where application is running doesn't belong to our organization and still python2.4 installed :S. Solution is fixing config file and pay more attention next time ,)